# Index with a combination of one and two columns

Tags: formatting, indexing

I am using the following to create my index file.

```
heading_prefix "{\n\\bfseries\\color{black} "      % insert in front of letter
heading_suffix "\\hfil}\\nopagebreak\n"  % append after letter
headings_flag  1                 % turn on headings(uppercase)

delim_0 "\\dotfill"
```

The index entries appear in one column, which is fine.  I wonder if there is a way to make the sub index entries appear in more than one column, as they are short in length?

An MWE to illustrate is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,lipsum}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}

\setromanfont{Georgia}

\usepackage{index}\makeindex

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{theindex}
   {%\section*{\indexname}%
    \setlength\parindent{0pt}%
    \setlength\parskip{0pt plus .3pt}%
    \let\item\@idxitem
%    \vspace*{-25mm}
    }
\makeatother 


\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

Lorem \index{ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer} \index{adipiscing elit. Ut purus} elit, vestibu-
lum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris.
Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, \index{consectetuer id}, vulputate a, magna. Donec
vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi \index{tristique senectus} et ne-
tus et \index{form!malesuada} \index{form!fames} \index{form!ac} turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus
rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna \index{form!fringilla} \index{form!ultrices}. Phasellus eu
tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. \index{form!Integer} sapien est, iaculis in, pretium
quis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean
faucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, \index{form!mollis} \index{form!ac}, nulla. Cur-
abitur \index{form!auctor} semper \index{form!nulla}. \index{form!Donec} varius \index{form!orci} eget risus. \index{form!Duis} \index{form!nibh} mi, congue
eu, \index{form!accumsan} \index{form!eleifend}, \index{form!sagittis} \index{form!quis}, \index{form!diam}. \index{form!Duis} \index{form!eget} \index{form!orci} \index{form!sit} \index{form!amet} \index{form!orci} \index{form!dignissim}.
rutrum.

\bigskip

\printindex

\end{document}
```

I have used the following instructions to create the index file.

xelatex tst.tex

makeindex -s MyIST.ist tst.idx

xelatex tst.tex

evince tst.pdf

The content of MyIST.ist is follows.

```
heading_prefix "{\n\\bfseries\\ "      % insert in front of letter
heading_suffix "\\hfil}\\nopagebreak\n"  % append after letter
headings_flag  1                 % turn on headings(uppercase)

delim_0 "\\dotfill"
```

As seen from the output, all the entries under 'form' are short in length.  I would like to arrange these entries in, say, 2 or even 3 columns, rather than 1 column as it stands.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @Jubobs I have added an MWE to my original question.

Comment: A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button ({}) or select your code and hit Ctrl+K.

Comment: @jubobs thank you.  I didn't know about Ctrl+K.

Answer (score 6):

Plan A set as a paragraph:

[image]

```
\renewcommand\subitem{\unskip\hspace{0pt plus .7\textwidth}\linebreak[3]\hspace{1em plus -.4\textwidth minus .2em}}
\printindex
```

or...

Plan B: set in 3 columns:

[image]

don't redefine `\subitem` instead

```
heading_prefix "{\n\\bfseries\\ "      % insert in front of letter
heading_suffix "\\hfil}\\nopagebreak\n"  % append after letter
headings_flag  1                 % turn on headings(uppercase)

delim_0 "\\dotfill"

item_x1 "\n\\begin{multicols}{3}\n\\subitem "
group_skip "\n\\ifdim\\columnwidth<\\textwidth\\end{multicols}\\fi\n\n \\indexspace\n"
```

and

add

```
\usepackage{multicol}
```

Answer (score 2):

Variant of David's plan A: Use my [`idxlayout`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLobp.jpg) package. (Note: Compile the following MWE using MakeIndex *without* any `-s` option.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{index}
\makeindex

\usepackage[columns=1,itemlayout=singlepar]{idxlayout}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.mst}
heading_prefix "{\n\\bfseries\\ "
heading_suffix "\\hfil}\\nopagebreak\n"
headings_flag  1
delim_0 "\\dotfill"
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

Lorem \index{ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer} \index{adipiscing elit. Ut purus} elit, vestibu-
lum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris.
Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, \index{consectetuer id}, vulputate a, magna. Donec
vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi \index{tristique senectus} et ne-
tus et \index{form!malesuada} \index{form!fames} \index{form!ac} turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus
rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna \index{form!fringilla} \index{form!ultrices}. Phasellus eu
tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. \index{form!Integer} sapien est, iaculis in, pretium
quis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean
faucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, \index{form!mollis} \index{form!ac}, nulla. Cur-
abitur \index{form!auctor} semper \index{form!nulla}. \index{form!Donec} varius \index{form!orci} eget risus. \index{form!Duis} \index{form!nibh} mi, congue
eu, \index{form!accumsan} \index{form!eleifend}, \index{form!sagittis} \index{form!quis}, \index{form!diam}. \index{form!Duis} \index{form!eget} \index{form!orci} \index{form!sit} \index{form!amet} \index{form!orci} \index{form!dignissim}.
rutrum.

\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]